# Cannot start ng test with --reporters option anymore

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I've been working on an Angular 5 application for a while now and typically start my tests using the following command:

```
ng test --reporters dots
```

This works as expected. I started a new Angular 6 project recently and thought I could use the same command to run my karma tests, but whenever I try and specify `--reporters` I get the following error:

```
Data path ".reporters" should be array.
```

This error doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me, and where exactly it wants this array. I do have a `reporters:` array in karma.conf.js, but it's the same as what I've got in my Angular 5 project.

For the record, `ng test` works just fine, but I prefer the dots output for local testing. I should also specify that any reporter I try to run from the command line also shows this exact behavior. I can't run the coverage reporters I'd like either.

Here is my [karma.conf.js](https://pastebin.com/abkwydHR). Relevant reporters section:

```
reporters: ['spec', 'kjhtml'],
```

I've tried adding `'dots'` to that as well, with no effect.

My package.json has the following two lines in scripts:

```
"test": "ng test --code-coverage",
"watch": "ng test --reporters dots",
```

`npm run test` works fine, but `npm run watch` does not. It gives the error reported above.

Relevant devDependencies:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.7",
"@angular/cli": "6.2.7",
"karma": "^1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.1",
"karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
"karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
```

Comment: @Mordred, Does your package.json consists of this line, `"test": "ng test"`? Or it is there with some additional parameters? And can you show how your `reporters` variable is defined in `karma.conf.json`?

Comment: @SaddamPojee Added some more information.

Comment: @Mordred With your above configuration, I'm still able to run `npm run watch` command successfully. I will recommend to update your `angular` and `angular-cli` to the most recent version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try add dots through [growl](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-growl-reporter) reporter.

```
npm install karma-growl-reporter --save-dev
```

Set configuration in `karma.conf.js`

```
config.set({
    plugins: [
         require('karma-growl-reporter'),
         ...
    ],
    ...
    reporters: ['spec', 'kjhtml', 'growl'],
 });
```

**UPDATE**

If you install `karma` from Angular/CLI (v 6.2.7) you need update this to v7.0.2 (`"@angular/cli": "~7.0.2"` in `devDependencies`).

*I think it because not provided `reporters` key in `v6.2.7` (I not found `reporters` in schema.json, however there is `v7.0.2`)*

**UPDATE**
From [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10852)  issue we can watch that v6.x.x was delete flag `--reporter`. It means we can't make report from console (`ng test --reporter` doesn't work).

There is variant when we are creating and adding reporter another karma2.conf.js by default like:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({

    plugins: [
     ....
         require('karma-growl-reporter'),
     ....
    ]
    ...
    porters: ['dots'],
```

and calling from console `ng test --karma-config PATH_TO_ANOTHER_KONF_FILE.js`

Comment: The issue isn't that the I don't have the dots reporter, it's that I can't specify any reporter. No matter what reporter I attempt to use from the command line, I get the `Data path ".reporters" should be array.` error.

Comment: Update "@angular/cli": "6.2.7", to "@angular/cli": "~7.0.2",

Comment: At the moment, I can't do that. Some of the dependencies of this project do not support Angular 7 yet.

Comment: Updated answer. From https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10852 you can create another karma2.conf.js and set your reporter only `dots`

Comment: Thanks! This appears to be the correct answer now. I won't be able to test and accept it until after the New Year though when I'm back in the office.

Comment: Can confirm that updating to Angular 7 fixed the problem.